# Buddypress single profile page show 404 error

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

I just put this code to get user id.

```html
<a href="<?php echo bp_get_member_user_id() ?>" target="_blank"
> class="">View Profile</a>
```

Now it's show the permalink as user id.

**localhost/demo/members/5**

But when I click view profile it's show 404.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

the function `bp_get_member_user_id` only return an integer (the userid)

in case your target is localhost/demo/members/5, try to use this code:

```
<a href="/demo/members/<?php echo bp_get_member_user_id(); ?>" target="_blank"
> class="">View Profile</a>
```

Comment: `echo esc_url( bp_get_member_user_id() )` always escape output.

Answer (score 0):

BuddyPress uses the user_name in a profile url. Unless you made changes to that functionality, an integer won't work.
Try:

```
<a href="<?php echo bp_core_get_user_domain( bp_get_member_user_id() ); ?>" target="_blank"> class="">View Profile</a>
```